# Maven - Different Dependency Version in Test

Tags: maven, hadoop, cloudera

I'm suffering an issue similar to [Maven 2 - different dependency versions in test and compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575742/maven-2-different-dependency-versions-in-test-and-compile) but the specified answer there does not work.

In my project I need to depend on a Cloudera distribution of Hadoop and a 'vanilla' version for JUnit testing, as the former only works on *nix.

When I try and execute my application, I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration`. When I run JUnit tests from Maven or Eclipse, everything works fine. If I comment out the `test` dependencies, the application runs successfully.

Why is the `compile` dependency getting ignored when the `test` dependency is uncommented?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.2-cdh3u2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

`mvn dependency:list` is shown below. The `compile` scoped version does not show up at all:

```
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    ant:ant:jar:1.6.5:test
[INFO]    aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO]    cglib:cglib:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO]    ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO]    ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO]    com.google.guava:guava:jar:r08:compile
[INFO]    com.h2database:h2:jar:1.3.164:test
[INFO]    com.jolbox:bonecp:jar:0.7.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.11:test
[INFO]    commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO]    commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:test
[INFO]    commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:test
[INFO]    commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:test
[INFO]    commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:test
[INFO]    commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:test
[INFO]    commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:test
[INFO]    commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0:test
[INFO]    commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.0.1:test
[INFO]    commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:test
[INFO]    commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    commons-net:commons-net:jar:1.4.1:test
[INFO]    hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.10:test
[INFO]    junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[INFO]    mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.18:compile
[INFO]    net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.7.1:test
[INFO]    net.sf.kosmosfs:kfs:jar:0.3:test
[INFO]    org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.1:test
[INFO]    org.apache.ftpserver:ftplet-api:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO]    org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-core:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO]    org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-deprecated:jar:1.0.0-M2:test
[INFO]    org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO]    org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-test:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO]    org.apache.mina:mina-core:jar:2.0.0-M5:test
[INFO]    org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO]    org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO]    org.eclipse.jdt:core:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO]    org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO]    org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:2.0.3:test
[INFO]    org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-slf4j:jar:0.0.1:test
[INFO]    org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:test
[INFO]    org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:test
[INFO]    org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-2.1:jar:6.1.14:test
[INFO]    org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-api-2.1:jar:6.1.14:test
[INFO]    org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:jar:2.5-20081211:test
[INFO]    org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api-2.5:jar:6.1.14:test
[INFO]    org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO]    org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO]    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.data:spring-data-hadoop:jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:c
ompile
[INFO]    oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:test
[INFO]    tomcat:jasper-compiler:jar:5.5.12:test
[INFO]    tomcat:jasper-runtime:jar:5.5.12:test
[INFO]    xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:test
```

Comment: What does `mvn dependency:list` show for `hadoop-core`?

Comment: @Raghuram I've edited the question to show this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a maven bug - or if not, something that is fishy enough I wouldn't trust the documentation if there were any.

In your case, I would probably:

1. upgrade maven and see if the issue is fixed in the latest m3
2. try repackaging one of the hadoop versions with another artifact id or group name. maven-shade-plugin, don't bother changing the package name, but just introduce something maven won't know is no different from org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core
3. try moving the tests to a separate project downstream
4. start debugging maven and understand what's going on exactly (and then fall back on 1 or 2...)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried option 2, but strangely it still showed the same behaviour. I'm wondering if there's something in one of the .jars causing the problem?

Comment: When trying 2, make sure you're fully shaded - if you still transitively depend on you original artifact, it won't work.

Answer (score 6):

What you desire, is no longer valid for Maven 3 (this used to be valid for Maven 2). Maven 3 will attempt to obtain the nearest dependency, effectively ensuring that only one of the compile or test scoped dependency is used for both the compile and test phases.

In your case `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:1.0.0:test` overrides `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:0.20.2-cdh3u2:compile` and hence becomes the nearest dependency. You may see the following warning displayed by Maven when running the `mvn dependency:list` goal, that alludes to this being a problem in your project model:

> [WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be
>   unique: org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar -> version 0.20.2-cdh3u2 vs 1.0.0 @ line xyz, column xyz

To 'fix' this, it would be better to split your tests into a separate project whose project model can define a separate set of test dependencies.