# Maven - version managed from x, omitted for duplicate?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I am having trouble with understanding what happens in maven dependency tree when it states version managed from x; omitted for duplicate.

For example, let's assume that I have `enterprise-data-2.4` defined in the dependency management section of `server-a`.

I get the following in the dependency tree of `server-a` for one of the dependencies `server-b` pulling in `enterprise-data-2.4`.

```
[INFO] +- hello.world.welcome.to:server-b:jar:3.1-SNAPSHOT:runtime
[INFO] |  +- (hello.world.where.am: enterprise-data:jar:2.4:runtime - version managed from 3.0; omitted for duplicate)
```

Assuming `server-b` is the only jar pulling in `enterprise-data-2.4`, my understanding is that `server-a` will always pull in `enterprise-data-2.4` here. Is this correct?

I however, have code in `server-b` dependent on `enterprise-data-3.0` and `server-b` has a compile time dependency on `enterprise-data-3.0`.

Now, I have a test project, let's say `test-b` which tests `server-b` jar present inside `server-a` project and has a test dependency on `enterprise-data-3.0`. These tests directly hit the code present on `server-a`.

When I run my tests in `test-b` should I get errors while attempting to access functionality present in `enterprise-data-3.0` since it's not being pulled in by `server-a` or will it pass because there is a test dependency on `enterprise-data-3.0`? It passes currently but I am not sure how a test dependency is sufficient.

Please help me understand.

Edit: I am using `maven-3`.

Thanks.

Comment: Maven dependency mediation for transitive dependencies works by using the first declaration as master. Since it's troublesome to keep track of transitive dependencies, you really should look into dependency management. Basically see my answer here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26317934/136363

Comment: @t0mppa - I am using dependency management for pulling in enterprise-data-2.4. Please read my question again.

Comment: Ok, reread and tried to answer your questions. If I still misunderstood you, please edit your question with some concrete examples.

Answer (score 10):

> For example, let's assume that I have *enterprise-data-2.4* defined in the dependency management section of server-a.

Then you always get 2.4 pulled in, even if there's only JARs depending on 1.8 for instance. Dependency management overrides dependency mediation.

> Assuming *server-b* is the only jar pulling in *enterprise-data-2.4*, my understanding is that *server-a* will always pull in *enterprise-data-2.4* here. Is this correct?

Assuming you have no dependency management, then yes. If there are multiple dependencies that are dependent on different versions, then it's a question of which one (and its transitive dependencies) is loaded first, as per the dependency mediation rules for Maven version > 2.0.9. Others will be: "managed from x and omitted for duplicate".

> When I run my tests in *test-b* should I get errors while attempting to access functionality present in *enterprise-data-3.0* since it's not being pulled in by *server-a* or will it pass because there is a test dependency on *enterprise-data-3.0*? It passes currently but I am not sure how a test dependency is sufficient.

If it's pulling the wrong version with incompatible code, yes you will see errors. For Maven 3, defining a test scope dependency with 3.0 and compile scope dependency with 2.4 will mean that Maven overrides the 2.4 and goes with the newer one defined on test scope. See [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9364511/136363) for more details.

Nevertheless, you can always use dependency management in *test-b* to fix in the version of each dependency that you want to use.