how to use multiple versions of maven dependency
In my Java micronaut microservice, I want to use a version of a maven dependency for my main code and another different version of the same maven dependency for unit tests code. So, how can I achieve this?
I am trying to do something like this but it looks like it is using test version only that is 2.2.2 for both main and unit tests code.
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- version for main code -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>a.b.c.d</groupId>
                <artifactId>w-x-y-z</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- version for unit tests code -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>a.b.c.d</groupId>
                <artifactId>w-x-y-z</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


Maven 3 only "allows" this via a dirty trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67743309/1273080, otherwise it's forbidden. Would you mind telling us what are you actually trying to achieve? Why you think two different versions are necessary? This really smells as usually you want to have the same versions in test and in prod.

You can achieve this with Gradle: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-override-version-only-for-test-compile-and-running-tests/35074
